# Android: Have sequential calls using Transformations.switchMap in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm trying to have 2 sequential calls to network where the second one has as parameter the result of the first one. I'm trying doing it using MVVM and Transformations.switchMap I get an Exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class com.rdev.image.obj.FlickrResultSize". Does anyone know how to do it?

```
public LiveData<ArrayList<String>> getValuesAPI(String url) {

    LiveData<ArrayList<String>> ids = AbsentLiveData.create();
    LiveData<ArrayList<String>> urls = AbsentLiveData.create();
    final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> updatedResult = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    //This method waits until it has the data to process
    ids = Transformations.switchMap(getValues(url), apiResponse-> {
        ArrayList<String> listaIds = new ArrayList<>();

        if(apiResponse.isSuccessful()) {

            if (apiResponse.body != null) {

                FlickrPhotos flickrPhotos = new FlickrPhotos();
                flickrPhotos = apiResponse.body.getPhotos();
                FlickrResultSize flickrResultSizes = new FlickrResultSize();

                for(int i=0;i<flickrPhotos.getPhoto().size();i++){
                    String id = flickrPhotos.getPhoto().get(i).getId();

                    String link = Utils.createURL(2,id);

                    flickrResultSizes = getPhotos(link); -----------I want to call this, but I can't
                    Timber.d("depois do getPhotos");
                    listaIds.add(id);


                }

                updatedResult.postValue(listaIds);
            }

        }
    });

  return ids;
}
```

//call network

```
public FlickrResultSize getPhotos(String link){
    return mMainApiHelper.getPhotos(link);
}
```

Comment: @MartinMarconcini any suggestion here?

Comment: @CommonsWare any suggestion here?